# How to create a modal activity which causes code code on background activity after it's finish()?

Tags: java, android

*Old Title: Continue execution of code from activity 1 only after activity 2 finish()*

Let's consider this code:

```
    // Call activity to take some pictures
    Intent i = new Intent(MainAct.this, CameraAct.class);
    startActivity(i);
    // After CameraAct is closed (finish()) then send pictures to webservice
    sendPicturesToWebService();
```

I know this code is wrong because after run `startActivity(i)` the code will not wait until that new activity finishes to run `sendPicturesToWebService()` like if the new intent was a model window/screen.

**How can I get this done?**

*by 'this' I mean: create and show a new activity as if it was a modal window / a dialog window; and continue to execute code from old activity right after the modal activity is closed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to `startActivityForResult()` and then handle the "result" on the `onActivityResult` callback. Here the link reference to the official docs:

[startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

[onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)